# Dynamic 'Like' in oracle (Spring)

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am trying to use a parameter in the 'like' however, when I call the method it generates error, I have tried these ways and all generate error

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BOOK l WHERE l.NAME LIKE LIKE '%'||:search||'%'", nativeQuery = true)
List<BookEntity> findByParam(@Param("search") String search);
```

**Error**: ORA-00936: missing expression

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BOOK l WHERE l.NAME LIKE %:search%", nativeQuery = true)
List<BookEntity> findByParam(@Param("search") String search);
```

**Error**: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BOOK l WHERE l.NAME LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%',:search),'%'), nativeQuery = true) 
List<BookEntity> findByParam(@Param("search") String search);
```

**Error**: ORA-00904: "CHARLIE": invalid identifier

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Ditch the query and write your method like `findByNameLike` and Spring Data JPA will do everything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try directly binding the entire wildcard expression to the `:search` placeholder

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BOOK l WHERE l.NAME LIKE :search", nativeQuery=true)
Collection<Book> findByName(@Param("search") String search);
```

In your calling code, you would use this snippet:

```java
String search = "%CHARLE%";
List<Book> books = yourJpaRepository.findByName(search);
```